# American English Idiom "Out of this world" and Sentence Stress

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

what does this idiom mean "Out of this world". Does it mean something like "Excellent" or "Awesome"?

When I'm eating something and I say: "It's out of this world." Which words gets most stressed in this sentence?

Any suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

"Out of this world" is a rather out-of-date idiom meaning "very good" or "unusual" (in a positive sense). Like, "Wow, this pizza is out of this world!", meaning it is very good. Do not emphasize any word in the phrase over the others.

I think there is a law in the United States that every science fiction movie must be described as "out of this world" some time during the marketing or promotion for that movie. At least, I hear the phrase used to describe just about every SF movie. Like many witticisms, it was no doubt very funny the first time someone used it that way. By the four hundred and twelfth, it's not.

Comment: There can be some stress in the idiom, usually equally on "out" and "world." To stress the entire idiom, drawl "world." E.g., "Oh, man, that pizza was out of this woooooorld!"

Answer (score 0):

The literal meaning, which is rarely (never?) used, is that the thing is supernatural. ("This world" is the mundane, physical plane.) The idiomatic meaning is that it is unusual in a good way.